# jQuery datepicker, selecting specific date in the range

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker and I want to make a specific range just to be available on the check in and checkout field, e.g you can only choose dates in the fields from 11th may to 15th may, other fields must be disabled. This current code does that you cannot book earlier than today, and that you cannot checkout on the same day as you check in, but I need this function of specific dates.

```
        $(function(){
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
            onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
            }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + <?php echo  $bsiCore->config['conf_min_night_booking']; ?>);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
            //alert(newDate);
            //alert(checkout.setValue(newDate));
            }
            checkin.hide();
            $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
            }).data('datepicker');
            var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
            onRender: function(date) {
            var checkoutdt= parseInt(checkin.date.valueOf())+(60*60*24*1000*<?php echo  ($bsiCore->config['conf_min_night_booking']-1); ?>);

            return date.valueOf() <= checkoutdt ? 'disabled' : '';

            }
            }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            checkout.hide();
      }).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: What's your problem then?

Comment: My problem is that I want only specific and also static dates - e.g. I, as a customer, can only choose from 11th May to 15th May. Other dates are disabled. @trevster344 I

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datepicket property minDate for check in date i.e. in your case 11th may and maxDate to new Date() or in your case 15th May.

```
$('#dpd1').datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2016, 05 - 1, 11),
  maxDate: new Date()
});

$('#dpd2').datepicker({
  maxDate: new Date()
});
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote similar code for the jQuery datepicker which shares a lot of similarities but is not the same. Build off of this.

```js
$('input').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var endDate = new Date(2017, 4, 15);
            var startDate = new Date(2017, 4, 11);
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
                return [false, 'my-custom-class', '']; //between 11 and 15
//Set to true, and it will only apply a class to those days but allow any days to be selected
            }

            return [true, '', '']; //Default return
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='text' value=''/>
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday